# Nats jetstream load balancing

Tags: go, geolocation, nats-jetstream, anycast

Using nats websocket in a Browser and wanting it to connect to the nearest physical nats Server and to load balance across the 3 servers per data center.

The docs are vague about this.

The servers know if all other servers and so it seems when a client connects you get back a list of them but I have 10 data centers with 1 nats Server in each but the geo lb is not working .

Anyone else have any tips ?

I have test harness code on GitHub where the client and server debug logs are in the gui to help see what’s happening.

I also am using nats.Go compiled to wasm and running in a service worker inside the browser . Mainly because the nats.go code is aligned with the nats Server golang code .